# Jquery flot chart: Want to show days in X-axis

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

I've a `JQuery` flot chart:

[image]

**HTML**

```
               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
                    <div class="portlet">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>Visitors
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <div id="site_statistics_loading">
                                <img src="assets/img/loading.gif" alt="loading"/>
                            </div>
                            <div id="site_statistics_content" class="display-none">
                                <div id="site_statistics" class="chart">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END PORTLET-->
                </div>
```

**JS**

```
        initCharts: function () {
            if (!jQuery.plot) {
                return;
            }

            var data = [];
            var totalPoints = 250;

            // random data generator for plot charts

            function getRandomData() {
                if (data.length > 0) data = data.slice(1);
                // do a random walk
                while (data.length < totalPoints) {
                    var prev = data.length > 0 ? data[data.length - 1] : 50;
                    var y = prev + Math.random() * 10 - 5;
                    if (y < 0) y = 0;
                    if (y > 100) y = 100;
                    data.push(y);
                }
                // zip the generated y values with the x values
                var res = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) res.push([i, data[i]])
                return res;
            }

            function showTooltip(title, x, y, contents) {
                $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                            position: 'absolute',
                            display: 'none',
                            top: y + 5,
                            left: x + 15,
                            border: '1px solid #333',
                            padding: '4px',
                            color: '#fff',
                            'border-radius': '3px',
                            'background-color': '#333',
                            opacity: 0.80
                        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
                }

            var Last_Week = [
                [1, 3],
                [2, 345],
                [3, 34],
                [4, 234],
                [5, 435],
                [6, 458],
                [7, 879]
            ];

            var This_Week = [
                [1, 134],
                [2, 789],
                [3, 423],
                [4, 416],
                [5, 489],
                [6, 157],
                [7, 340]
            ];

            if ($('#site_statistics').size() != 0) {

                $('#site_statistics_loading').hide();
                $('#site_statistics_content').show();

                var plot_statistics = $.plot($("#site_statistics"), [{
                        data: Last_Week,
                        label: "Last Week"
                    }, {
                        data: This_Week,
                        label: "This Week"
                    }
                ], {
                    series: {
                        lines: {
                            show: true,
                            lineWidth: 2,
                            fill: true,
                            fillColor: {
                                colors: [{
                                        opacity: 0.05
                                    }, {
                                        opacity: 0.01
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        points: {
                            show: true
                        },
                        shadowSize: 2
                    },
                    grid: {
                        hoverable: true,
                        clickable: true,
                        tickColor: "#eee",
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    colors: ["#d12610", "#37b7f3", "#52e136"],
                    xaxis: {
                        ticks: 11,
                        tickDecimals: 0
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        ticks: 11,
                    }
                });

                var previousPoint = null;
                $("#site_statistics").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                    $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
                    $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));
                    if (item) {
                        if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                            $("#tooltip").remove();
                            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(0),
                                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(0);

                            showTooltip('', item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + "&nbsp;" + y);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $("#tooltip").remove();
                        previousPoint = null;
                    }
                });
            }               

            if ($('#load_statistics').size() != 0) {
                 //server load
                $('#load_statistics_loading').hide();
                $('#load_statistics_content').show();

                var updateInterval = 30;
                var plot_statistics = $.plot($("#load_statistics"), [getRandomData()], {
                series: {
                    shadowSize: 1
                },
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 0.2,
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: {
                        colors: [{
                                opacity: 0.1
                            }, {
                                opacity: 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    tickFormatter: function (v) {
                        return v + "%";
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    show: false,
                },
                colors: ["#e14e3d"],
                grid: {
                    tickColor: "#a8a3a3",
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
                });

                function statisticsUpdate() {
                plot_statistics.setData([getRandomData()]);
                plot_statistics.draw();
                setTimeout(statisticsUpdate, updateInterval);

                }

                statisticsUpdate();

                $('#load_statistics').bind("mouseleave", function () {
                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                });
            }
```

So, my question is that I want to show days instead of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. I have tried to do this :

```
var Last_Week = [
                ["Sun", 3],
                ["Mon", 345],
                ["Tue", 34],
                ["Wed", 234],
                ["Thu, 435],
                ["Fri", 458],
                ["Sat", 879]
            ];

var This_Week = [
                ["Sun", 134],
                ["Mon", 789],
                ["Tue", 423],
                ["Wed", 416],
                ["Thu", 489],
                ["Fri", 157],
                ["Sat", 340]
            ];
```

But it show me this:

[image]

Its mean I'm wrong somewhere. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Please narrow down your problem, try using the console, look for errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining a number of ticks for your xaxis (`ticks: 11,`) specify an [array with the labels](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) of the ticks (and stay with the numbers in the data, this is a [must](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format)):

```
ticks: [[1, "Sun"], [2, "Mon"], [3, "Tue"], ...]
```